# Gridsome Develop Request failed with status code 404

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, gridsome

I keep getting errors with Gridsome starters when executing the `gridsome develop` command.

I've tried the default starter that Grisdome recommends and now the Contentful Starter so far and errors keep showing up in the terminal.

Here is the error I get with the Contentful starter:

```
Initializing plugins...
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (/var/www/public/my-project/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:886:15)
    at settle (/var/www/public/my-project/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:1049:12)
    at Unzip.handleStreamEnd (/var/www/public/my-project/node_modules/contentful/dist/contentful.node.js:294:11)
    at Unzip.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1183:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

And here is the error from the default starter:

```
Error
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:150:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:141:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:770:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:782:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:431:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:415:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:305:11)
    at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:594:10)
    at Socket.end (net.js:574:31)
    at handleInput (/var/www/public/myblog/node_modules/imagemin-pngquant/node_modules/execa/index.js:87:17)
```

Comment: You have to add your contentful `SPACE_ID` and `ACCESS_TOKEN` in gridsome.config.js. Without that you won't able to proceed.